# How to Get Plist Data and Display in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, plist

I have some data in plist.First of all i want to get the plist data and Then display in UITableview.
My plist Sequence is just like this

**Root...........Dictionary**

**item 0-9.......Array.**[image]

In ViewDidload my code is look like this.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movies" 
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Here is confusion for me that how To pass the my Array item to UITableview.
Can some one help me that how to display all this data in UITableview.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the Array for section A:

```
NSArray *arrayForA = (NSArray *)[dic objectForKey:@"A"];
```

Then you'll have an array of the items there that can be displayed in a UITableView. Same for B and C.

If you want to display those as sections, then I would build an array of arrays.

If you need help actually making the UITableView and displaying it, take a look at Apple's [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).